# How to extract multipliers from strings?

Tags: python, string, game-development, dice

I'm a fresh python learner and  I came up with a simple game I'd like to try coding. It's pretty simple gameplay-wise, but coding it is harder than I expected it to be.
Explanation:
2 players face off with 3 Monsters on each side (kinda like Pokemon but with more RNG)
These monsters have stats (HP, ATK, SPD) and 6 unique abilities/attacks that they use based on the dice roll you got.
Now here's where it gets tricky for me.
For example, Monster A deals 5x ATK damage when you roll a 1.
I have this monster as an object, which contains a string for each dice roll possible (1-6)
In this case, Monster A.dice1 would be the string "Deals 5x ATK DMG to enemy"

Now, how do I extract this multiplier (5x) so that I can multiply Monster A's ATK?
There are also other abilities that can lower the enemy's ATK for example.

I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The way this would typically be implemented would be to use attributes on your monster, not through parsing strings. For example:

```
MonsterA = {
  'type': 'monster',
  'atk': 50,
  'atk-multiplier': 5,
  'crit-roll': 1
}
if dice_roll == MonsterA['crit-roll']:
  dmg = MonsterA['atk'] * MonsterA['atk-multiplier']
```

That said, to answer your question, string parsing can be tricky, and it depends a bit on the source of your strings. If your strings are all like this one, and they range from "Deals 5x ATK DMG to enemy" to "Deals 10x ATK DMG to enemy", then you have some options:

To just extract numbers from a string:

```
extracted_number = 0
for char in dice_string:
  if char.isnumeric():
    extracted_number = int(char)
```

To separate a string into "words":

```
words = sentence.split(" ")
# words == ["Deals", "5x", "ATK", "DMG", "to", "enemy"]
mulitiplier = words[1]
```

Comment: I somehow pressed enter and it sent the comment immediately, sorry. Thank you very much, you made the solution look very easy and understandable. Now i have a rough plan of how to do the calculations. Now I need to find a way to implement diverse stuff like applying status effects etc. and I'm set